# How can I open the same form with two different buttons from two different forms and know which button was clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form (form1) that I use to create a new record in a sheet when I open it from form2. I would like to open the same form (form1), but from another form (form3) to update the info that I have already entered.

How can I know from with form did I opened the form1 so I can decide if it will come clean or with info to update?

I've tried creating a public variable in each form to save which button was clicked and a select case decide the state of the form but this approach doesn't seem very maintainable.

Comment: Look for OpenArgs, you can provide passing arguments when opening form. These arguments are processed in Form_Open or Form_Load event, and then you can write proper code, or define the source opening form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you have the opening routine within Form1 and call it from your other forms, passing in the sender as a parameter? As below:

**Userform1**

```
Private mSender As MSForms.UserForm
Public Sub OpenForm(sender As MSForms.UserForm)
    Set mSender = sender
    Me.Show
End Sub
```

**Userform3**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.OpenForm Me
End Sub
```